# query not translated by in Entity Framework, .net Core 3.1

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-core

We recently started migration of an .net core 2.1 application to .net core 3.1, after upgrading EF to 5.0.9 some of our existing queries errored out.  Reading up on it seems like there were changes made to have the queries avoid being executed on the client, unless it's part of a Select projection.

One of the solutions around this was to add AsEnumerable or ToList to the query, forcing it to execute before the next part runs which can not be translated to direct SQL.

The below query worked earlier:

```
unitOfWork.GetRepository<MAPPING_TABLE>().GetAll(predicate: x => x.USER_ID == userId).AsNoTracking()
                            .Include(p => p.Site).ThenInclude(p => p.Provier).ThenInclude(p => p.Location).AsNoTracking()
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Site.SM_PROVIDER_ID).Select(y => y.First()).ToList().
                             Count();
```

Adding the AsEnumerable got it to work with lastest EF, otherwise it was erroring, complaining the GroupBy() could not be translated:

```
unitOfWork.GetRepository<MAPPING_TABLE>().GetAll(predicate: x => x.USER_ID == userId).AsNoTracking()
                            .Include(p => p.Site).ThenInclude(p => p.Provier).ThenInclude(p => p.Location).AsNoTracking()
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Site.SM_PROVIDER_ID).Select(y => y.First()).ToList().
                             Count();
```

Is there another way to write that query, without having to the AsEnumerable before the GroupBy?

Comment: Very often it's possible to start the query one level higher in the object hierarchy, which provides a natural grouping without needing `GroupBy`. We'd have to see the class model to see if this is possible at all.

Comment: Well, why you need first grouped element if you just count unique `x.Site.SM_PROVIDER_ID`?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need grouping, includes, AsNoTracking for such simple query:

```cs
unitOfWork.GetRepository<MAPPING_TABLE>().GetAll(predicate: x => x.USER_ID == userId)
    .Select(x => x.Site.SM_PROVIDER_ID)
    .Distinct()
    .Count();
```